# Flutter try reload NetworkImage

Tags: flutter

I have a feed on images in my app. I display a placeholder for each of them while they are loading. While the feed is loading and all the placeholders are displayed and I have an internet connection problem, they will stay and display the placeholders forever, even if my connection problem is solved, I still have the placeholders there. I would like to retry to load the images again in case the first attempt threw an error.

I have tried to catch the error with `.catchError()` and then make a recursive call to the function `_loadItem` again after 30 seconds. Problem is that the error is not caught correctly because it does not call the function `_loadItem` again.

Could anyone please tell me what am I doing wrong here, and might suggest a better approach to what am I doing if applicable?

Some might suggest `cached_network_image` package but I would like not to use it.

Below is my code.

```
class FeedItem extends StatefulWidget {
  final Item item;
  FeedItem({
    required this.item,
    Key? key,
  }) : super(key: key);

  @override
  _FeedItemState createState() => _FeedItemState();
}

class _FeedItemState extends State<FeedItem> {
 bool _itemLoaded = false;

 @override
 void initState() {
  _loadItem().catchError((error, stackTrace) {
   Future.delayed(const Duration(seconds: 30), () => _loadItem());
  });
 } 

 Future _loadItem() async {
  ImageStream imageStream = NetworkImage(widget.item.url).resolve(ImageConfiguration());
  imageStream.addListener(ImageStreamListener((ImageInfo info, bool syncCall) {
   setState(() => _itemLoaded = true);
  }, onError: (err, stackTrace) {
    throw 'Error loading image';
  }));
 }

 @override
 Widget build(BuildContext context) {
  return AnimatedCrossFade(
    firstChild: buildFeedItem(), // image loaded
    secondChild: buildFeedItemPlaceholder(), // image loading
    crossFadeState: _itemLoaded ? CrossFadeState.showFirst : CrossFadeState.showSecond,
    duration: const Duration(milliseconds: 500),
  );
 }
}
```